# Implement Search Bar on Activity Load

Tags: java, android, xml, search, full-text-search

I want to load an activity and have the search bar visible right away with a magnifying glass available to click/search based on the term entered. Here is what I want to see when I load the activity:

[image]

Code:

```
public class FlickRActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flick_r);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
     }

 }
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/hint_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `searchItem.expandActionView();`